# Why doesn't memory taken by atom in Erlang depend on its length?

Tags: erlang

Erlang atoms were said to be taking only 4 or 8 bytes in space, no matter how long they are.
How can they do it? Is it truly no consuming memory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it truly no consuming memory?

An atom refers to an ID of an atom table which **also consumes memory** and is managed by Erlang's VM called [BEAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BEAM_(Erlang_virtual_machine)), which is the virtual machine at the core of the Erlang Open Telecom Platform [OTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Telecom_Platform).

This ID is represented by a machine integer (4 bytes on 32-bit and 8 bytes on 64-bit systems) and can change when the VM is restarted after a shut-down and a tuple containing those atoms is reinstantiated.

The atom text itself is stored once for each unique atom in this table. The atom table is not garbage-collected.

Characters in an atom are limited to 255, by default, the maximum number of atoms is 1048576. This limit can be raised or lowered using the +t option.

Please refer to the official docs [here](http://erlang.org/documentation/doc-5.8.4/doc/efficiency_guide/advanced.html) and [there](http://erlang.org/documentation/doc-5.3/doc/efficiency_guide/advanced.html) for more detailed information about atoms.

For general info about datatypes you may read [this article](https://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/data_types.html)